# Existence of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove whether there exists a holomorphic function in the unitary disk such that $|f(z)| = e^{|z|}$ for all $|z| < 1$. I'm trying to apply Schwarz's Lemma since I would easily get a contradiction from there but I'm not sure how to deal with the hypothesis of $f(0) = 0$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: maximum modulus principle applied to $1/f$.